# Церковь или церковь?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Когда речь идет не о храме, а о религиозном институте, как правильно писать слово "церковь": со строчной или прописной? Например, правильно ли так: Истинно-Православная Катакомбная Церковь?

Comment: См. параграф 184 "Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации" под редакцией В.В. Лопатина.

Comment: Это не сюда. На политику.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вряд ли можно сказать, как ПРАВИЛЬНО.Словари, изданные сегодня с одобрения Орфографической комиссии,  различаются в своих рекомендациях,что свидетельствует о том, что представленный к утверждению раздел не проработан до конца.В "Справочнике по правописанию и лит. правке"Розенталя 2000-х годов читаем:"С прописной буквы пишутся слова, обозначающие важнейшие для православной традиции понятия: Слово (В начале было Слово), Небо (Уповаю только на Небо), Крест Господень, Страшный суд, Святые Дары, Святой Дух, Великая суббота, Русская Православная Церковь, Успение Богородицы."  
http://www.lingvotech.com/relig
В то же время в секторе орфографии и орфоэпии Института русского языка им. В.В.Виноградова РАН была подготовлена новая редакция правил употребления прописных и строчных букв. Она получила одобрение Орфографической комиссии при Отделении литературы и языка РАН и стала размещаться в словарях. В сравнении с приведенными выше рекомендациями Справочника Розенталя в данном тексте есть много изменений и уточнений. Раздел «Названия, связанные с религией» содержит следующие рекомендации: писать с прописной буквы в первую очередь первое слово в названиях конфессий (§ 28), высших органов церковной власти и некоторые слова (объяснения нет) в полных официальных наименованиях высших церковных должностей (§ 29). Таким образом, если по рассмотренной выше редакции Справочника предлагалось написание Русская Православная Церковь, то данная редакция предлагает написание Русская православная церковь, Священный Синод изменил написание на Священный синод (хотя в усеченном названии, следуя ссылке на § 34, необходимо писать Церковь и Синод - как в условных наименованиях-символах)
http://www.praedicatores.ru/index.php/articles/223-pravila

Answer (score 3):

В религиозной литературе принято с заглавной буквы писать всё, что имеет хоть какое-то отношение к религии. С точки зрения светской орфографии, тут имеет смысл писать с заглавной только первое слово.

Вообще как раз в написании заглавных букв сейчас в орфографии полнейший сумбур вместо музыки. Розенталь в этом вопросе сильно устарел, а Лопатин далеко не всеми признан.

Comment: "... сумбур вместо музыки" - это же цитата из Постановления ЦК ВКП(б) о журналах "Звезда" и "Ленинград"; медаль Д. Д. Шестаковичу от Секретаря ЦК А. А. Жданова. Комментарий не к месту, но не смог удержаться, завидев  знакомые с детства слова.

Answer (score 1):

Тут не в религиозной составляющей дело. Просто по мнению сторонников заглавных подобные названия являются именами собственными.
Как Красная Шапочка или Чингачгук Большой Змей.
Хотя кое-кто и против заглавного Змея возражает...

Comment: Да и в религиозной тоже, слово "православие" никаким боком нельзя отнести к именам собственным, но с заглавной, пишут его часто.

Comment: Это другое. Из серии наш Президент - с заклавной, а буржуинский - он и со строчной сойдет. Т.е. религиозный мотив можно, конечно, найти в рекомендациях Церкви о написании некоторых слов (**Б**ог, Святой **Д**ух и проч.; частично, кстати, разделяемой и официальной орфографией), но ни Ваш пример, ни исходный я бы не объяснял с таких позиций.

Comment: А я в википедии нашла - все писалось с большой буквы.

Comment: Наш президент пишется со строчной буквы. С прописной пишется в полном наименовании Президент РФ.
Всё

Comment: Я даже Председатель колхоза пишу с прописной буквы, но не призываю к этому других. Почему? Авторское право, поскольку комментарий - документ не официальный, а в правилах - сумбур вместо музыки, по @Яzz

Comment: @FuchoinKazuki В Википедии любой прохожий может написать или отредактировать статью, и она довольно долгое время пробудет без рецензии. Так что Википедия — плохой пример.

Comment: @русак ага, Председатель Колхоза (... Краснознаменного Ордена Красной Звезды Имени Ленина).

Answer (score 1):

"Вообще как раз в написании заглавных букв сейчас в орфографии полнейший сумбур вместо музыки".

Порядок в написании прописных/строчных букв  навести несложно, если рассматривать не каждое составное название, а задать СТАТУС словам, входящим в эти названия. Это выглядит примерно так.

1. Следует отличать термины (нарицательные существительные) от имен собственных. Например, православие, церковь - эти слова  являются терминами: православная церковь,  католическая церковь, отцы церкви.
2. Эти же слова могут входить в составные имена собственные, в которых с прописной буквы пишутся 4 вида слов: а) первое слово; б) все условные названия; в) слова особой важности; г) входящие имена собственные. Например: Православная церковь, Русская православная церковь - это составные имена собственные, названия РЕЛИГИОЗНЫХ ОРГАНИЗАЦИЙ, и здесь только первое слово пишется с прописной буквы, остальные слова с реальным, а не условным значением  пишутся со строчной буквы.

(Для сравнения: Северный Ледовитый океан - здесь второе слово имеет УСЛОВНОЕ  значение и поэтому пишется с прописной буквы.Но: Северный морской путь -  второе слово имеет РЕАЛЬНОЕ значение и пишется со строчной буквы).

1. В религиозных кругах всем названия придается статус ОСОБОЙ ВАЖНОСТИ, именно поэтому они пишутся с прописной буквы. Например,  мы можем зайти на официальный сайт Русской Православной Церкви.

Answer (score 1):

Если мы не пишем, согласно нормам светской орфографии, Государство, когда речь идёт об институте и мы используем слово-термин, то не нужно писать в аналогичном случае Церковь. Конструкция "отношения государства и Церкви" выглядит с позиций светской (общенаучной) орфографии странно. Так и во многих других случаях - "общество и Церковь" и т. д. Здраво объяснить правомерность такой конструкции невозможно. Получившая в 90-е гг. практика употребления варианта "Церковь" без учёта контекста - отражение смены идеологических ориентиров некоторой части научного сообщества, представителей СМИ, но такого рода конъюнктурная ситуация не должна становиться нормой.